# Django manage.py runserver never finishes "validating models"

Tags: django, django-manage.py

I am trying to follow the django tutorial. I am running on windows+eclipse. 
When I run `python manage.py runserver` I get the message `Validating models...` and afterwards see no progress...

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got my answer in another question: [can't get django to work in eclipse + windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173603/cant-get-django-to-work-in-eclipse-windows)

When I ran the server with the --noreload option, I saw that there's an exception thrown. After I fixed that, the output *does* complete, and says:

```
Validating models...
0 errors found

Django version 1.2.1, using settings 'XXX'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

Answer (score 0):

The shell is running the `runserver` process, and it won't go back to a command prompt until the server process ends. So, this sounds normal.

Is the server functioning?

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly be importing something in your models.py file that is failing in another file. I had an import in a try/catch clause that caused this behavior.  Installing the missing dependency fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

This is what you're supposed to see.  If you make a request to your test site (via your browser), you will see the log of the request.  If you don't see that, then something else is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, this is incorrect - I've now got it working and it does in fact print something afterwards. this is the complete output:

Validating models...
0 errors found

Django version 1.2.1, using settings 'XXX'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.