# can't get django to work in eclipse + windows

Tags: django, eclipse, pydev

I've installed django on my windows machine, added the pydev and django plugins for eclipse, create a django project, and ran `manage.py createapp` to create one app. Now when I run `manage.py runserver` (via eclipse's "custom command" option") It says `Validating models...` but when I go to http://localhost:8000 I get no response, as though the server is not running. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746512/pydev-and-django-how-to-restart-dev-server/7648375#7648375 for a solution with autoreload turned on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running with `--noreload` to avoid getting two processes. It helps with error output redirection in eclipse, and may give you more hints towards the actual problem.

Also, do the same from the command-line to see if you get the same problem.

**Update:** Per Fabio's comment above, you can work around this problem by hacking the code, as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746512/pydev-and-django-how-to-restart-dev-server/7648375#7648375).